# How do I connect to the already opened Chrome Browser

Tags: watir

Is there any way can I connect to the already opened chrome browser through watir? I think it's possible in Chrome but not possible in Firefox?

Comment: Do you mean to connect to a browser that you've manually opened (as opposed to one opened by Watir)?

Comment: If the Chrome browser is started with `--remote-debugging-port=xxxx` you can pass in `debugger_address: "localhost:xxxx"` as an option and it will connect to that existing instance.

Comment: @JustinKo yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @titusfortner can you please write an answer?

Comment: @titusfortner I tried this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application>msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9014` and it opens the edge browser but the watir program I write `require 'watir'
options = { 'debuggerAddress' => '127.0.0.1:9014' }
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:edge, options)
browser.goto('https://www.example.com')` throws this error, please see the next comment...

Comment: >ruby hi.rb
C:/Ruby32/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/watir-7.3.0/lib/watir/capabilities.rb:29:in `to_args': {"debuggerAddress"=>"127.0.0.1:9014"} are unrecognized arguments for Browser constructor (ArgumentError)

      raise ArgumentError, "#{@options} are unrecognized arguments for Browser constructor" unless @options.empty?
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 from C:/Ruby32/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/watir-7.3.0/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
 from hi.rb:7:in `new'
 from hi.rb:7:in `<main>'
>Exit code: 1

Comment: The parameter name changed - see answer in your other question.

Comment: @JustinKo I solved this problem. Selenium adds the switch `--test-type=webdriver`, If this switch is found then it's stopping the site to display all the options. If we remove this switch, then all the options are available.

Comment: @titusfortner I solved this problem. Selenium adds the switch `--test-type=webdriver`, If this switch is found then it's stopping the site to display all the options. If we remove this switch, then all the options are available.